# Xcode wont pick the right account for uploading from archiving

Tags: swift, xcode, app-store-connect

[link on what is happening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9PLqO.png)

when i try to upload my app keeps giving me this error
[Xcode archive doesnt recognize my developer account](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AhnMl.png)

Comment: Try removing the account from Xcode, adding it back in again, clicking "Download All Profiles", and re-archiving the app. Once you have done that,  if it still doesn't work, please post a screenshot from "Manage Certificates..."

Comment: It did not work this time, It has worked before with another App I have done, so I dont know the issue is

Comment: @Coder256, he is the images for Manage Certificates, http://imgur.com/a/wlilj

Comment: Strange, try clicking on "Download All Profiles". Next, go in to the xcode project for the app, then set code signing to none, then set it back to your team.